# Definition of Set Union explanation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In proving the identity (A∖B)∩C = (A∩C)∖(B∩C),

> If x ∉ B, then x ∈ B', by definition of set complement. Using the definition of set union, we can extend the last statement and rewrite it as x∈(B' ∪ C').

how come is it logically true that if x is assumed to be outside a set (compliment) then its partner with either union or intersection would also be assumed that x is outside of it?

in this case (x ∈ C ∩ x ∈ B') therefore x ∈ (B' ∪ C'). can someone please elaborate the "definition of set complement".

[image: Image solution link]

Comment: for further information, this is example 1 on this [link](https://www.math24.net/set-identities/#example1)

Comment: Something doesn't seem right here. If $x \in C \cap B'$, then $x \notin C'$. We have $C \cap B' \subseteq B' \cup C'$, since $x \in C \cap B'$ implies $x \in B'$ implies $x \in B' \cup C'$, but it's not equality.

Comment: ill add screenshot of the solution given in the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the link is saying is this: take $x \in (A \setminus B) \cap C$. We have $x \in A \setminus B$ and $x \in C$, so $x \in A$, $x \notin B$, and $x \in C$. This implies $x \in A \cap C$. If $x \notin B$ (as we just assumed) then $x \in B^c$ by definition (since $B^c$ is the set of all elements not in $B$). Now if $x \notin B$, then we also get that $x \in B^c \cup C^c$ (all this is saying is that $B^c \subseteq (B^c \cup C^c)$). By DeMorgan's, $B^c \cup C^c = (B \cap C)^c$, so $x \notin B$ gives us that $x \in (B \cap C)^c$. Putting everything we have together, $x \in A \cap C$ and $x \in (B \cap C)^c$, so $x \in (A \cap C) \setminus (B \cap C)$.

**So what they've shown is the following:** $(A \setminus B) \cap C \subseteq (A \cap C) \setminus (B \cap C)$.

Notice their goal is **not** equality (yet). The first part of the solution is just trying to show this is a subset. The second part of the solution is trying to show $(A \cap C) \setminus (B \cap C) \subseteq (A \setminus B) \cap C$, which will give you equality.